# sed and capture

Tags: regex, sed

I'm trying to get

${test-value} (although I would prefer just test-value)

from this expression

```
echo 'test=${test-value} ... more text' | sed 's/\${[^}]*}/&/'
```

but it just prints the input

I think I'm matching like this,

1. $
2. {
3. Zero or more characters not }
4. }

but clearly I'm not or perhaps I'm missing something else.

Comment: Not clear, please post more clear examples in CODE TAGS `{}` button while you post and clearly mention what you are looking for in your POST.

Comment: Tell us exact input and output that you are expecting

Comment: It's ok. I'm happy with the solution I got from Wiktor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You match `${test-value}` with `\${[^}]*}`, but you replace it with itself as `&` in the replacement pattern stands for the whole match value.

Use the following fix if you want to use `sed` (to match the whole string but capture what you need and keep it by using a `\1` placeholder in the replacement pattern):

```
sed 's/.*\(\${[^}]*}\).*/\1/'
```

Or use a matching approach (with `grep` using `-o` option to extract the matched text):

```
grep -o '\${[^}]*}'
```

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/z5iSZH).

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know grep could do it as well.